# Multidimensional dictionary losing lower levels after for loop in the django template

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I have a dictionary of players and their inventory. There is a lower level dictionary for each item with the needed values. On the template I would like to do a for loop through each item and get their dictionaries. I will give a simplified example which hopefully makes it clearer to understand. Please let me know if there is something unclear about my question or examples.

```
views.py

players = {}

players[1] = {}
players[1].update({
  'avatar': user.avatar,
  'username': user.username,
})

players[1]['items'] = {}
  
players[1]['items'][item.id] = {}
players[1]['items'][item.id].update({
  'item_name' = item.name,
  'item_value' = item.value,
})
```

```
template.html

{% for item in players.1.items %}
  {{item}} <!-- Gives me item ids -->
  {{item.1.item_name}} <!-- I would expect that to give me the value of item_name, instead I get nothing -->
{% endfor %}

{{players.1.items.1.item_name}} <!-- This works as it gives me the result I am expecting -->
```

Answer (score 1):

The dictionary can be iterated using the key value in the Django template. the extra ".items" gives key and value records separately in the loop. Try renaming fields to avoid the ".items" confusion.

```
{% for key, values in players.1.items.items %}
  {{key}}
  {{values.1.item_name}} 
{% endfor %}
```